# How to give configurable URL in tableau WDC

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to build a tabeau WDC.

this is my code

```
(function () {
    var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();

    myConnector.getSchema = function (schemaCallback) {
        var cols = [{
            id: "month",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string
        }, {
            id: "value1",
            alias: "value1",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.float
        }, {
            id: "value2",
            alias: "value2",
            dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.float
        }];

        var tableSchema = {
            id: "testfeed",
            alias: "test Feed",
            columns: cols
        };

        schemaCallback([tableSchema]);
    };

    myConnector.getData = function (table, doneCallback) {
        $.getJSON('http://test.com/view?name=test&filters=[{"type":"number","id_equals":["123"]}]', function (resp) {

            var feat = resp.DATA,
                tableData = [];

            // Iterate over the JSON object
            for (var i = 0, len = feat.length; i < len; i++) {
                tableData.push({
                    "MONTH": feat[I].month,
                    "ChargeEntryLag_NUMERATOR": feat[i]. value1,
                    "ChargeEntryLag_DENOMINATOR": feat[i]. value2
                });
            }

            table.appendRows(tableData);
            doneCallback();
        });
    };

    tableau.registerConnector(myConnector);
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submitButton").click(function () {
            tableau.connectionName = "testFeed";
            tableau.submit();
        });
    });
})();
```

my URL contains some filters as shown in the above code, so if U want to get data for a particular filter I have to hardcode it in URL and the use it.
In other word my URL is static , Is there a way to make it dynamic.
suppose I want the value of 'id' to be 10in my filter, for that I have to go the the WDC code and change it. can it be made configurable.

Answer (score 0):

use `tableau.connectionData` to pass data. There is an example in this tutorial:

https://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/docs/wdc_multi_table_tutorial

Typically you'd create a form. When you connect with the WDC in tableau desktop, you put in the URL of your form. The form will store the form vars in tableau.connectData. Your getData can then take those and create a custom Data Source inside tableau desktop for you.

- Mike